# Does a linear map on a tensor product of vector spaces induce linear maps on the individual spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products

Given vector spaces $U, V$, a linear operator $T$ on $U \otimes V$,
I am aware that $T$ is not necessarily the tensor product of linear operators on $U$ and $V$ respectively.

However, I am wondering if, given a vector $v \in V$, 
do $T$ and $v$ induce a linear operator on $U$?
I suspect this is true (unlike the case for direct sums),
but I can't determine this for sure.

In particular, if $U, V$ have inner products,
$T$ is unitary and $\left\lVert{v}\right\rVert = 1$,
is the induced linear operator unitary?

---

## My Attempt

$U \otimes v := \left\{ u \otimes v \ \middle\vert\  u \in U \right\}$
is a subspace of $U \otimes V$, since it contains $0 \otimes v = 0$,
and $\alpha (u \otimes v) + u' \otimes v = (\alpha u + u') \otimes v$

Define $\pi_1 : U \otimes V \to U$ by $\pi_1(u \otimes v') = u$.
Then 
$$
\pi_1\left(\alpha (u \otimes v') + u' \otimes v'\right) 
= \pi_1\left((\alpha u + u') \otimes v'\right) 
= \alpha u + u' 
= \alpha \pi_1(u \otimes v') + \pi_1(u' \otimes v') ,
$$
so $\pi_1$ is linear.

And define $\tau_v : U \to U \otimes V$
by $\tau_v(u) = u \otimes v$.
Then 
$$
\tau_v(\alpha u + u') 
= (\alpha u + u') \otimes v 
= \alpha (u \otimes v) + (u' \otimes v) ,
$$
so $\tau_v$ is also linear.

Then we can define the induced linear map $T_v$ by
$$
U \xrightarrow{\tau_v} U \otimes v \xrightarrow{T} U \otimes V \xrightarrow{\pi_1} U \ .
$$

I'm a little bit unsure though if this is well-defined.
I'm also not clear whether this may depend on the choice of bases for $U$ and $V$.
Part of the reason I'm not sure about this is because when we replace the tensor product with the direct sum, then the resulting map is affine linear (I believe).

---

## Unitary

Let $U, V$ be inner product spaces and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ the induced norm.
Then by the standard definition, 
$\left\lVert u \otimes v \right\rVert = \left\lVert u \right\rVert \cdot \left\lVert v \right\rVert$.

If $T$ is a unitary operator on $U \otimes V$ 
and $\left\lvert v \right\rangle \in V$
such that $\left\lVert v \right\rVert = \left\langle v \middle\vert v \right\rangle = 1$,
then $\left\lVert \tau_v(u) \right\rVert = \left\lVert u \right\rVert \left\lVert v \right\rVert = \left\lVert u \right\rVert$
and $T$ does because it is unitary.
But I cannot tell whether $\pi_1$ is.
Is there some way to demonstrate that $\pi_1$ preserves norms?

Alternatively, is there some other way to induce a linear map on $U$?
I suspect it must require the choice of a particular $v \in V$ (but this is okay with me),
otherwise $T$ would factor $S_U \otimes S_V$ into linear operators on $U$ and $V$.
Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that doesn't work here is that $\pi_1$ is not well defined.

Linear maps from $U\otimes V$ to $W$ correspond to bilinear maps from $U\times V$ to $W$.
The correspondence is if $T:U\otimes V\to W$, then $S:U\times V\to W$ is defined by $S(u,v) = T(u\otimes v)$, and conversely, if $S:U\times V\to W$ is bilinear, then $T$ is defined by linear extension from the pure tensors, $T(u\otimes v)=S(u,v)$.

Now you've defined $\pi_1 : U\otimes V \to U$ on the pure tensors by $\pi_1(u\otimes v)=u$. However, this should correspond to a bilinear map $S:U\times V\to U$ defined by $S(u,v)=\pi_1(u\otimes v)=u$. This is not bilinear, since $S(u,2v)=u=S(u,v)\ne 2S(u,v)$ according to this definition.

**However!** If we have an inner product, and a chosen $v_0\in V$ (of norm 1), we can fix this! (I assume the second coordinate of inner product is my linear coordinate)
Define 
$S:U\times V\to U$ by
$$S(u,v) = \langle v_0,v\rangle u.$$
You can check that this is bilinear now. Thus it induces a map, I'll call $\pi_{v_0} : U\otimes V \to U$, defined on pure tensors by $\pi_{v_0}(u\otimes v) = \langle v_0,v\rangle u$.

**Is $\pi_{v_0}$ unitary?**

The answer is **no**, not in general. No such map can be actually unless $\dim V =1$. The problem is that unitary maps are injective, but if $\dim U = n >0$, $\dim V = m>1$, then 
$\dim U\otimes V = nm > n = \dim U$. Thus no such map can be injective, and thus no such map can be unitary.

However, if $\dim V=1$, then $\pi_{v_0}$ will be unitary.
We check that it preserves the inner product. It suffices to check on the pure tensors. Let $u\otimes v$ and $u'\otimes v'$ be pure tensors. $v=xv_0$, $v'=x'v_0$, for $x$ in the base field, since $V$ is one dimensional.
Then 
$$\langle u\otimes v, u'\otimes v'\rangle 
= \langle u,u'\rangle \langle xv_0,x'v_0\rangle 
$$
$$= \langle u,u'\rangle \overline{x}x'
$$
$$= \langle u,u'\rangle \overline{\langle v_0,xv_0\rangle } \langle v_0,x'v_0\rangle
$$
$$= \langle \langle v_0,v\rangle u, \langle v_0,v'\rangle u'\rangle
$$
$$=\langle \pi_{v_0}(u\otimes v), \pi_{v_0}(u'\otimes v')\rangle,
$$
as desired.

Comment: I figured there was something fishy about $\pi_1$. I was thinking too much about $U \otimes v$ and forgot to consider linearity of the second coordinate. I guess then if we knew that the dimension of the image of $T$ was $\dim U$, then your construction would also work?
Either way, thanks for all the help!